# Como ler uma variável no setText()?

Tags: c++, string, qt

Preciso que o texto de um `lineEdit` seja igual a uma variável *string*.

Estou usando esse código:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){

    string texto;
    texto= "mensagem";
    ui->lineEdit->setText(texto);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Qstring texto;
    texto = "mensagem";
    ui->lineEdit->setText(texto);
}
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QStringLiteral("mensagem"));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Qt/SetText.cpp).

O `QStringLiteral` é uma macro presente na Qt 5 que cria um literal do tipo `QString` sem precisar fazer conversão em tempo de execução.

O `setText` do `LineEdit` espera uma `QString` e não uma `string` padrão do C++, por isto não funcionava.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: @SamuelBratiFavarin se funcionou **marque** a resposta como correta, se não sabe fazer isto leia as dicas aqui de como usar o site: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: Qual a diferença entre 'QString' e QStringLiteral'?

Comment: @Lucas o 1o. é o tipo e o 2o. é uma macro p/ gerar o literal sem fazer conversão, se quiser saber mais detalhes, faça uma pergunta.